# From Decision Tree to Dataframe or List

Tags: r, list, tree

I have the following J48 decision tree (res): (This is an example)

```
> res
J48 pruned tree
------------------

Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (50.0)
Petal.Width > 0.6
|   Petal.Width <= 1.7
|   |   Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48.0/1.0)
|   |   Petal.Length > 4.9
|   |   |   Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (3.0)
|   |   |   Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (3.0/1.0)
|   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     5

Size of the tree :  9
```

It is created as followed:

```
library(RWeka) 
data(iris) 
res = J48(Species ~., data = iris)
```

I would like to transform it into dataframe or list in the following format:

```
source_node1 target_node1
source_node2 target_node2
```

Here is the required result:
First format (with numbers):

```
Petal.Width_0.6 Petal.Width_1.7
Petal.Width_1.7 Petal.Length_4.9
Petal.Length_4.9 Petal.Width_1.5
```

Second format (same with no numbers):

```
Petal.Width Petal.Width
Petal.Width Petal.Length
Petal.Length Petal.Width
```